# How to configure Tomcat to use SSL encryption with the private key stored on a remote server?

Tags: encryption, ssl, tomcat, private-key

I want to know if there is a way to configure Tomcat `server.xml` to use the SSL 
encryption with a private key stored remotely on a server
I can imagine the server configuration would be something like this

```
Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
proxyPort=""
keystoreFile="{./script-return}/keystore.jks"
keystorePass="12345"
keystoreType="jks"
truststorePass="12345"
maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

But the `keystoreFile` directive to point to a script which extracts the private key from the remote server.

Is there a way in Tomcat configuration to make it point to a shell script to extract the key?

I found something about [TrustManager](https://lightbend.github.io/ssl-config/KeyStores.html) but I can see the path has to point to a file system path, which is not an alternative for me.

Comment: Does the key have to be stored in a specific format and/or downloaded over a specific protocol, or do you just need _any_ technology that would allow this?

Comment: Yes. They key can be accessed only using the PCKS#11 provider in order to reach the HSM

Comment: Also can you clarify whether the HSM and Tomcat are located on two different Linux systems, or whether they're actually on the same system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Extracting the key" quite defeats the point of using an HSM – it means the private key would still be stored in Tomcat's memory (so it would've been possible to steal using e.g. Heartbleed), and anyone looking at the `server.xml` could still steal it by **simply running the exact same command** as Tomcat does.

Your idea only makes sense if you can make Tomcat *send signing requests* to the HSM. This will increase latency a bit (due to every single TLS connection having to hit the HSM), but it's the only approach that actually adds some security.

(It doesn't even need to be a real HSM; it could even be SoftHSM2 running on the same system, and it would still be more secure as long as it firmly keeps the key on one user account and Tomcat on the other.)

**Using a PKCS#11 module on the same system**

You can fast-forward through this section, but the basic steps for using PKCS#11 with Tomcat are:

1. Create an `/etc/java-<name>.cfg` file with:

   ```
   name = <hsm_name>
   library = /usr/lib/p11-kit-proxy.so
   ```

   (Adjust the library path according to your distro. The full documentation of this config file can be found in the [Java PKCS#11 guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html#Config).)
2. Add a new line to your `java.security` file:

   ```
   security.provider.NUM=sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 /etc/java-<name>.cfg
   ```
3. Run keytool and make sure it shows your HSM contents:

   ```
   keytool --list --storetype PKCS11
   ```
4. Finally, configure Tomcat to use PKCS#11:

   ```
   <Connector ...
              keystore="NONE"
              keystoreType="PKCS11"
              keystoreProvider="SunPKCS11-hsm_name"
              keystorePass="[HSM PIN here]" />
   ```

**Using a PKCS#11 module from a remote server**

The *p11-kit* package comes with two components which can achieve this:

1. The `p11-kit-proxy.so` PKCS#11 module, which acts as a multiplexer and can be configured to load various other modules according to configuration. Among other things, it can communicate with an out-of-process module over a pipe.
2. The `p11-kit remote` tool, which acts as the other pipe end for p11-kit's out-of-process module support. It can be used over SSH or any other tunnel.

So first on the HSM side:

1. Install p11-kit and choose or create a user account that will be using it.
2. Create a `~/.config/pkcs11/modules/<name>.module` file in that user account to tell p11-kit about your HSM PKCS#11 module. The file's contents consist of one line:

   ```
   module: /usr/lib/<hsm_pkcs11_name>.so
   ```

   (Alternatively you can create this in the system-wide directory `/usr/share/p11-kit/modules/`.)
3. Make sure `p11-kit list` and `p11tool --list-tokens` work with the HSM.

Note: The steps 2–3 aren't actually needed for this plan; they're only there so that possible problems could be noticed early on. If it turns out that p11-kit is incompatible with the HSM module, that'll save you some work. (And if it is compatible, then you'll be able to use `p11tool` to manage it.)

Then on the Tomcat side:

1. Install p11-kit as well.
2. Create an SSH keypair for Tomcat, and put it in the HSM account's `authorized_keys` for password-less SSH usage.
3. Again create a `~/.config/pkcs11/modules/<name>.module` file in the Tomcat user account's home directory, but this time the file's contents should look like this:

   ```
   remote: |ssh user@hsmserver p11-kit remote /usr/lib/<hsm_pkcs11_name>.so
   ```
4. Again, make sure `p11-kit list` and `p11tool --list-tokens` work. They should just magically establish an SSH connection and show information about the remote HSM.
5. To speed up the remote access, enable connection multiplexing in SSH via `~/.ssh/config`:

   ```
   Host hsmserver
       ControlPath ~/.ssh/S.%r@%h:%p
       ControlMaster auto
       ControlPersist 1h
   ```

If everything works, try to use `keytool` with the p11-kit-proxy PKCS#11 module:

1. Create an `/etc/java-p11-kit.cfg` file with:

   ```
   name = p11-kit
   library = /usr/lib/p11-kit-proxy.so
   ```

   (Adjust the library path according to your distro. The full documentation of this config file can be found in the [Java PKCS#11 guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html#Config).)
2. Add a new line to your `java.security` file:

   ```
   security.provider.NUM=sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 /etc/java-p11-kit.cfg
   ```
3. Run keytool and make sure it shows your HSM contents:

   ```
   keytool --list --storetype PKCS11
   ```
4. Finally, configure Tomcat to use the p11-kit-proxy PKCS#11 module:

   ```
   <Connector ...
              keystore="NONE"
              keystoreType="PKCS11"
              keystoreProvider="SunPKCS11-p11-kit"
              keystorePass="[HSM PIN here]" />
   ```

Comment: I have named my module with name=MyPKCS11 and when I load the Tomcat connector configuration I get the following error message in tomcat `LifecycleException:  service.getName(): "Catalina";  Protocol handler start failed: java.io.IOException: Failed to load keystore type PKCS11 with path NONE due to no such provider: SunPKCS11-MyPKCS11` Any suggestions ? The error i receive is for the local connection

Comment: Is the provider recognized by `keytool -list -storetype PKCS11`? Could it be that Tomcat uses a different JRE than the rest of the system and doesn't pay attention to your new `security.provider` settings?

Comment: I guess you are right.There seems to be an issue with loading the java security settings or so, since I was not able to make the keytool list the certs without specifying the provider parameters as well. Here is the full command it worked for me: `keytool -list -storetype pkcs11 -providername SunPKCS11-MyPKCS11 -providerclass sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 -providerarg /etc/alternatives/jre_1.8.0_openjdk/lib/security/pkcs11.cfg` Also the library `p11-kit-proxy.so` is not showing me any  certs data in keytool, but only the `libsofthsm2.so` does. This could be an issue in switching to remote?

Comment: Yes, keytool has the nice option of dynamically adding a provider, unfortunately Tomcat does not (or at least I couldn't find any) so it really needs to be in java.security for Tomcat...

Comment: As for p11-kit-proxy, does `p11-kit list-modules` recognize your configurations? Maybe it indeed cannot connect to the remote via ssh.

Comment: After long troubleshooting, I have found out that the `java.security` file was wrong and I had to specify a number to `security.provider.13=sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11`. Now, the `keytool --list --storetype PKCS11` command shows me the entries from SoftHsm. My current issues is Tomcat giving me `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` code error. I guess I wrongly created and imported the Self Signed Cert into the SoftHSM.  The commands that I found to do that are from [here](https://github.com/opendnssec/SoftHSMv2/issues/315). My thoughts are: I should make the local work before changing it to a remote.

Comment: IIRC, `softhsm2-util` only works with raw key pairs (producing "Public Key" objects), but most programs expect to find a "Certificate" object instead. (Indeed Tomcat needs to send the certificate to clients...) So I would use `keytool` or `pkcs11-tool` to import the certificate to the SoftHSM. You can also try Portecle or Keystore Explorer apps.